# Ubuntu keeps filling up despite no installs

Tags: storage

I just cleared more than 600 MB of systemd journal files. I started VirtualBox, tried to create a new machine, and found out I couldn't. I type in `df /` on the command line. There's no space left!!! What could have taken up 600 MB in few a minutes?!

This has been going on for a while now. I clear out space on my drive and then the space fills up so damn quickly. What is causing this?

Comment: Check your log files in /var/log and subdirectories.  What size / are we talking about?  There's a default 5% reserve for the system, but your user "out of space" message is at the 95% level.

Comment: Sounds like you have an error that is generating lots of log entries try journalctl -p 3..0
to list errors and see where that takes you

Answer (score 0):

Taking your exact question literally: which is :

> What could have taken up 600 MB in few a minutes?!

You can look for all files created newer than a specific reference point by explicitly setting the timestamp on a reference file with [touch(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) and then using [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to look for files newer than that file:

```
$ touch -t 202307092200 ref ; # create a file called ref for 10p local time on 2023-07-09
$ find . -newer ref
```